# Fit an image inside a div that also has a title?

Tags: html, css

Here's my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ab1wxn7a/)

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="block">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martz90/circle/512/camera-icon.png" />
</div>
```

I'm trying to have an image inside my block. I want to size the image so that it fits inside the block fully. I've tried with height 100% but the title of the block is not taken in to consideration and the height overflows the block.

Comment: Have you tried setting the image as the div background?

Comment: Which version of IE do you need to support? (*flexbox or not* as noted in a comment to an answer below). Is it possible to add 1 or 2 div as parent of `img` (I mean h2+div>div>img in ZenCoding notation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility that gives just one constant-pixel value (repeated once):

```
.block h2 {
  height: 30px;
}

.block img {
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

Comment: Thank, but I will not know the height of the h2, could be anything

Comment: @panthro Understood. I don't suppose your browser support only includes browsers that support the `display: flex` property in some capacity? That might let you do this.

Answer (score 2):

Try `display:table`

```
.block{
    display: table;
}
```

```css
.block{
    width: 30%;
    height: 100px;
    display: table;
    background: pink;
    
}

img{
   height: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martz90/circle/512/camera-icon.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, how could I center the image - and not the text?

Comment: @panthro, if none of the answers worked or you are still facing trouble, let me know so I can help

Answer (score 0):

```
margin-top:-18px
```

You can also try just moving the image
Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r1r76e4o/)

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do?

If you want do image background - use background-image and fit it

Anyway you can do something like this:

```
.block{
    width: 30%;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    background: pink;
    position: relative;
}

img{
   height: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
}

h2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 100px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fe11zyh9/1/

Answer (score -1):

Is it a possibility to set the height of the IMG in px?

So:

```
img{
   height: 100px;
   max-width: 100%;
}
```